# Excel VBA trouble-shooting -- what's causing the program to freeze up when I run this sub?

Tags: excel, vba

I've written an Excel VBA sub that's causing the program to freeze up. I've isolated the problem to a Do-Until loop within the sub.

A little background information first:

I have two sheets that I need to merge. After merging, some of the rows will contain duplicate data. Duplicate rows will have the same value in column D.

The Do-Until loop compares the column D value in each row with that of the row below. If the values are the same, that row gets deleted. I also use a special row numbering formula in column A, so whenever there's a delete, the sub copies the formula from the current row to the row below, since the deletion messes up the references in the formula. The loop continues until it reaches an empty row.

Currently, the sheet has almost 500 rows, so it's a lot of data, but not THAT much, right? The sub was created in Office 2003 and is in an xls file. I'm currently running Office 2010 and work with the file in compatibility mode.

Anyway, I've copied the code for the loop below. Does anyone have any ideas why the loop might be causing the program to freeze up? Thanks in advance.

```
Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)

' Define rows and cells
  Row1 = ActiveCell.row()
  RowPlus1 = ActiveCell.row() + 1
  RowMinus1 = ActiveCell.row() - 1

  Row1Student = "D" & Row1
  RowPlus1Student = "D" & RowPlus1

  Row1Number = "A" & Row1
  RowMinus1Number = "A" & RowMinus1

  If Val(Range(Row1Student)) = Val(Range(RowPlus1Student)) Then
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Range(RowMinus1Number).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range(Row1Number).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
  End If

  ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

Loop
```

PS: I'm not a professional programmer by any means. I taught myself VBA, so I'm fully aware that my code might not be very clean. That's why I'm hoping to get some feedback from people who've actually had training in VBA.

Edited to add: Okay, I removed the copy-and-paste part of the loop, and that seemed to speed things up considerably. So, does anyone have any ideas why that particular part of the sub is creating a problem?

Comment: It's hard to identify the problem in the loop when you don't show one in your code. :-) Can you edit and add the missing info (the loop itself, which would include the exit condition)?

Comment: Make a copy of your worksheet and remove all but 3 or 4 rows. Then step through the code (press F8 to advance line by line) until you get to where you expect the loop to complete. You will probably see what's wrong.

Comment: Oops, my bad. I've edited the code excerpt now. Sorry, not sure why the formatting is messed up.

Comment: Off the top of my head (w/o any testing), it looks like you're getting down to the final row and then endlessly looping because the `IsEmpty(ActiveCell)` never returns true. (You select the last row, can't delete the one after it, but have nowhere to go except the current `ActiveCell`.) As @HeadofCatering says, reduce to a small sample of data and step through the code, and you'll find it.

Comment: Woo hoo. Okay, it was the last row. Thanks!

Comment: @KenWhite I reckon that comment would make a good answer.

Answer (score 5):

Off the top of my head (w/o any testing), it looks like you're getting down to the final row and then endlessly looping because the IsEmpty(ActiveCell) never returns true.

(You select the last row, can't delete the one after it, but have nowhere to go except the current ActiveCell.)

As @HeadofCatering says, reduce to a small sample of data and step through the code, and you'll find it